# Excel file from Sharepoint to SQL Server Database

Tags: excel, api, sharepoint, ssis, odata

I am trying to create a SSIS package to load the data from a excel file on SharePoint to the SQL server database. The OData connection manager shows Test connection succeeded but my Odata Source Editor is giving error "Unable to load collection for the connection SharepointData, reason:Cannot open this connection. There are multiple tabs on the excel data which i need to load to a separate sql table. Does anyone know about this issue? How can i load all the excel tabs into a sql server?

https://adxcomp.sharepoint.com/teams/CustomerData/Documents/General/Customer - Weekly Update Files/Sales Detail - Report/-vti_bin/listdata.svc

I tried the above url but was unable to resolve the issue.

I would really appreciate for any kind of information.

Comment: I would handle this in 4 steps. 1) Download the file to file system 2 3 & 4) A data flow for each tab

Comment: I don't know where i got 3 tabs. but it should be a data flow per tab